# How can I add a user to my database with SimpleMembership outside of the MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my Accounts controller:

```
WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
```

This works and when I enter in a new line with the words WebSecurity I see intellisense provides me with all the options I expect.

I added the same code to another class but this time I have no options with WebSecurity. The class shows up but there are no methods that I can use.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong. How can I add a user outside of my controller to seed the database.

Here's what I am doing:

```
WebSecurity.CreateAccount("xx", "xx", true)
```

Here's the error message:

```
Error   2   'WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(string, string, bool)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the needed details, but I guess you have this line

```
WebSecurity.CreateAccount("xx", "xx", true)
```

not in a method. Like this (this will cause the error you're describing):

```
class AccountsController
{
   WebSecurity.CreateAccount("xx", "xx", true);
}
```

Check your syntax. Please post more code around the erroring line if this doesn't work.